# How can I download games on a WIFI tablet without WIFI

Tags: wireless-networking, tablet

Hello I have a Wifi tablet that I just bought. We don't have Wifi but we have a CELL C  USB that we use for internet on the laptop .... what can I do to download games with the USB and without WIFI

Comment: You need to be way more specific about what kind of tablet you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If your tablet supports USB on the go. You can use Micro-USB host cable, like this one - [image] And connect to the internet. 
Your tablet would automatically detect it.